# How to replace part of a string up to third occurrence of delimiter?

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have a string like

> AAA: BBB: CCC: DDD: EEE

and I need to replace

> AAA: BBB: CCC:

with

> FFF:

so it would look like

> FFF: DDD: EEE

Thanks.

Comment: You meant "up to **3**rd occurrence"

Comment: What's wrong with `s/AAA: BBB: CCC:/FFF:/`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Right. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU `sed` and extended regular expressions (`-r`), the following should work:

```
sed -r "s/^([^:]*:){3}/FFF:/"
```

either as in `sed <...> filename.txt` or `echo "$original_string" | sed <...>`

This will replace a substring that, starting with the beginning of the line (`^`), contains three times in a row a pattern consisting of "anything but the colon (`[^:]`)" followed by a colon, with the pattern `FFF:`.

Comment: Nice! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Also works on the MacOSX BSD sed, except change `-r` to `-E` (which also works with GNU sed) -- think of -E as enabling extended regular expressions in the same way that `grep -E` does.

Answer (score 0):

You cud use this:

```
$ sed -e 's/:/\n/3;s/.*\n/FFF:/' file
```

Here we are making use of the feature found in sed to effect the n-th change , n<=512. Also, the newline is guaranteed to not be seen in a pattern space, unless it has been brought in apriori, by means of the G, H, N, or a literal newline is added, like in our case.

This is gnu sed-ism. We use the escaped literal newline for Posix sed.